# Using a version of Ekeland variational principle to minimize a functional

Tags: calculus-of-variations, elliptic-equations, linear-pde, variational-analysis, elliptic-operators

Consider the problem
\begin{cases}
-\Delta u = |u|^{p-2}u, \Omega \\
\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,u = 0, \partial \Omega,
\end{cases}
where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ and $2 < p < 2^{*}$. The functional associated to the problem above is given by $I(u) = \frac{1}{2}||u||_{H^{1}_0(\Omega)}^2 - \frac{1}{p}|u|_{p}^{p}$, that is
$$
I'(u)\varphi = \int_{\Omega} \nabla u \cdot \nabla \varphi - \int_{\Omega} |u|^{p-2}u \varphi, \quad \forall u, \varphi \in H^{1}_{0}(\Omega).
$$
The Nehari manifold associated to $I$ is defined by $\mathcal{N} = \{u \in H^1_0(\Omega) \backslash\{0\} : I'(u)u = 0\}$. An outhor I'm studying used a version of Ekeland variational principle to minimize the functional $I$ on $\mathcal{N}$. The result is in the paper "On the variational principle, Ekeland, 1974, COROLLARY 3.4:

Let $F$ be a Fréchet-differentiable function and $G$ a $C^{1}$-function such that
$$
G(v) = 0 \implies G'(v) \neq 0.
$$
Supose moreover that
$$
\exists m \in \mathbb{R} : G(v) = 0 \implies F(v) \geq m.
$$
Then, for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists some point $v_{\epsilon}$ and some $\lambda_{\epsilon} \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $G(v_{\epsilon}) = 0$ and $||F'(v_{\epsilon}) - \lambda_{\epsilon} G'(v_{\epsilon})|| \leq \epsilon$.

The author I'm studying applied the agove result with $G(u) = I'(u)u$. However, in this case we have $G(0) = 0$, but $G'(0) = 0$.

What I missed?